# Creating an 'IF' statement for datatypes in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I'm kind of new to all of this and was hoping I could get some help. Some background that leads to my question is that I am building a small php interface that outputs a table. That table gets values from SQL Server. I have to display 4 tables. 3/4 table display successfully and dynamically (where if the a column or row is added on the SQL server side it will update the php interface tables automatically). The 4th table is giving me an issue. I've at least identified why it breaks the job; the reason is because two columns in the table are 'date_time' values in comparison to varchar or nvarchar values.

Essentially, the way i have it framed up in my head is to create an 'IF' statement in my 'for_loop' that will read the data type of each column, and IF it is a date_time type it will put it in the correct PHP date format, and if not it will put it in the regular format. (this maintains dynamics within the interface, i've done it all successfully, by hard coding the columns, but i'm trying to make my interface 'future-proof')

this is what i had in mind for an if statement:

let's say $field is equivalent to the columns data/value/datatype. This is the variable i use to echo the data from sql server.

```
$field = sqlsrv_get_field($result, $i);
if(gettype($field) == DateTime)
{
     echo "<td>".date_format($field, 'Y-m-d H:i:s')."</td>";
}
else
{
    echo "<td>".$field."</td>";
}
```

I've tried it and it doesn't work. Any suggestions would be helpful, and please keep in mind I am a rookie, so if you could simplify as much as possible that would be greatly appreciated! :)

Thanks again for taking the time to read this, and if you need more information from me, let me know.

Kazmi

Comment: Hm according http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php gettype doesn't return DateTime

Comment: no i didn't bksi, good point tho, however i found another solution, check below. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to edittor's link, i dug a little further and found a solution. For anyone else who runs into a similar problem, converting dates into string works best, at least for my use case.

here's my code:
$serverName = server
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>:"enter db", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"password", **'ReturnDatesAsStrings'=> true, "CharacterSet" => 'utf-8')**;
$con = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

^^^Returndatesasstrings should be included in your connect statement, from my understanding when it connects to your sql server database and pulls the information.schema it reads which column is 'datetime,date,time,timestamp,etc.' and converts into a string rather then a data value.

Hopefully this helps someone else. Also i find it odd that there isn't much on MSSQL in comparison to MYSQL on this website.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this one instead gettype

```
 mysql_field_type(data,field_offset)
```

and use quotes in if condition

have a look here for  details http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-type.php

For mssql you can use `mssql_field_type` 
 have a look here for details http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-field-type.php

Comment: I think he uses mssql instead mysql

Answer (score 0):

1: gettype() returns only the following datatype strings: "boolean", "integer", "double", "string", "array", "object", "resource", "NULL", "unknown type" (source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php)

2: Querying a MySQL database in PHP returns always strings, so even if the gettype function would know about "DateTime" it just would return "string".

Comment: he tagged the question with 'mysql', but you're right sqlsrv_get_field() is for MSSQL

Comment: $field = sqlsrv_get_field($result, $i); is not mysql

Comment: I bet it also returns only strings ;)

Comment: It can return integers too (mixed sqlsrv_get_field ( resource $stmt , int $fieldIndex [, int $getAsType ] ))

Comment: yes, seems it does return different data types.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296193.aspx

Comment: I tagged mysql to get attention to my issue a little faster due to the amount of use cases where people usually use MYSQL rather then MSSQL. The reason why I've come to understand that the value of the data coming in is a factor is because the table that i'm trying to put the data in on the php interface goes out of wack. However the working piece of code that i have works; I create a select query that pulls specific columns, and identify what columns i need to output data; the ones that i know are DATETIME values in sql server i modify as so:

Comment: echo "<td><span style=color:black>" . $row['AllObjectsCSVCreatedFlag'] . "</span></td>";
  echo "<td><span style=color:black>" . date_format($row['ProposedCSVCreationDate'], 'Y-m-d H:i:s') . "</span></td>";

Comment: the problem is I can't do that because, technically in the future I do not know whether a column will be added/not, and if so, i dont know whether they will insert a DATETIME column again. Hence why I want to make an IF statement (IF DATETIME VALUE THEN PUT IN 'DATE_FORMAT'), ELSE MAINTAIN REGULAR FORMAT. i just don't know how to express this in php, hence why i've come to this point now. Hope this clarifies things. Thanks